# Get id From checkbox gridview

Tags: c#, checkbox, gridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g2vV.png)

I dont know why my checkbox is error , everyone does it right except me

Comment: Simply, read what visual studio is saying to you.

Comment: i have fix it but i cant get the id value :(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are mixing the packages. Watch your imports - one is from System.Web.UI.WebControls and other is from System.Windows.Forms. Remove one or distinguish them.